# I wanted to add my setup at user/My Documents for every user using the inno setup but its not working for me

Tags: inno-setup

I wanted to add my setup at user/My Documents for every user using the inno setup but its not working for me.

Here i provide u my iis file.
Thanks in advance.
Please help me out.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!
#define MyAppName "Testing"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Test"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "testing.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{200DC169-9647-4295-91B4-B1D1D8482B82}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
;DefaultDirName={userdocs}\test
DefaultDirName={code:DefDirRoot}\test
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName=test
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
AllowNoIcons=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\abc\Desktop\final product\licence.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\abc\Documents\test
OutputBaseFilename=VL-PI Setup
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\abc\Downloads\clientcommentsveryimp\CORRECTIONS_TO_INSTALLER_BUGS\CORRECTIONS_TO_INSTALLER_BUGS\Icon\icon.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=none

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\Graphics"
Name: "{app}\lib"

[Files]
Source: "C:\test work\agriculture project requirments\jre-6u2-windows-i586-p.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall;
Source: "D:\final product\30-01-2013\test.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion;
Source: "C:\Users\test\Desktop\final product\Graphics\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Graphics"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\test\Desktop\final product\lib\*"; DestDir: "{app}\lib"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\VL-PI"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:uninstallProgram,VL-PI}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";
Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}";check:InitializeSetup; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
function Install_JavaFrameWork() : Boolean;
var
  hWnd: Integer;
  ResultCode: Integer;
  dotnetRedistPath: string;
  outVar : string;
begin

  dotnetRedistPath:= ExpandConstant('{tmp}\jre-6u2-windows-i586-p.exe');

try
  if Exec(dotnetRedistPath,'', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
     // ResultCode contains the exit code
     case ResultCode of
     // 1641 The requested operation completed successfully. The system will be restarted so the changes can take effect.
     // 3010 The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted. 
1641:
     begin
        Result := true;
     end
     3010, 0:
     begin
        Result := false;
     end else // -> case default
     begin
        Result := true;
     end
  end;

  end else
  begin
     //handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code
     Result := false;
  end;
  except
  ShowExceptionMessage;
  end;
end;


function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
 ErrorCode: Integer;
 JavaInstalled : Boolean;
 Result1 : Boolean;
 Versions: TArrayOfString;
 I: Integer;
begin
 if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', Versions) then
 begin
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Versions)-1 do
   if JavaInstalled = true then
   begin
    //do nothing
   end else
   begin
if ( Versions[I][2]='.' ) and ( ( StrToInt(Versions[I][1]) > 1 ) or ( ( StrToInt(Versions[I][1]) = 1 ) and (
 StrToInt(Versions[I][3]) >= 6 ) ) ) then
    begin
     JavaInstalled := true;
    end else
    begin
     JavaInstalled := false;
    end;
   end;
 end else
 begin
  JavaInstalled := false;
 end;

 //JavaInstalled := RegKeyExists(HKLM,'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.9');
 if JavaInstalled then begin
  Result := true;
 end 
 else begin
    if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\jre-6u2-windows-i586-p.exe')) then
    begin 
    Log('File exists');

Result1 := MsgBox('This program requires Java Runtime Environment version 1.6 or newer.Do you want to install it  now?',
   mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = idYes;
      if Result1 = false then begin
         Result:=true;
       end 
       else begin
          Install_JavaFrameWork;
           Result:=true;
       end;
  end else 
   begin 
    Result:=true;
    end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Firsrt of all, please [`edit your question`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14620597/edit) and re-paste your code, but now try to select the whole code in the post editor and press CTRL+K. That will format the whole block of your code. But the more important is to include in your question, what is the problem you're having. Terms like *"add my setup at user/My Documents for every user"* and *"its not working"* are vague. Which of the directives you want to default to the `..\User\My Documents` folder ? The `DefaultDirName` ? What is the exact problem you're having ?

Comment: @TLama I believe that Anurag wants his script to add File/Folder to My Documents folder so that every user that will log on the computer will see it. In my opinion he could just use `{commondocs}` (or other `common` variables), but maybe he wants add this File/Folder separately for each of system users? In that case it is more complicated.

Comment: By adding the setup, you mean copy the setup_myprogram.exe file to each user document's folder?

Answer (score 2):

An admin setup should never try and write to the user's profiles as they aren't guaranteed to be the user you expect or even accessable from that machine.

You're currently using `PrivilegesRequired=none` so it will not switch user, but that will stop you from installing Java for some users.
You should use `PrivilegesRequired=admin` for normal installations or `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` for user specific installations.

Comment: +1, nice catch about `PrivilegesRequired`, but it's really difficult what is being asked here :-)

Comment: Thanks its working for me.  I tested on Vista its working fine. i have to test it on other versions also.  I want that the setup will install the exe at  username\My Documents\   folder and its working for me using  PrivilegesRequired=lowest.   Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it's helped. Can you please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the green tick to the left of the post.